# Simple best file hosting service

Tags: file-hosting

I am searching for a file hosting service that has/supports:

- Up-to 100 files
- File sizes up-to 5 Mb
- No file expiration
- Direct download link to files
- Less than 5 $ or Euro/month fee
- Download stats, at least download count
- No download limit
- No bandwidth limit
- No ads if possible

Is there a service like this? If not what is the next best thing you recommend?

---

*Checked out Box.net, Rapidshare and MediaFire. They are not good for me.*

Comment: you will not find real 'no download limit', 'no bandwidth limit' at this price level. they will always have small print about 'acceptable usage terms' or other backdoor that will let them to kick you out, charge more or slow down your download speed.

Comment: +1 to counter the down vote. Seems like a perfectly reasonable question to me.

Comment: The question is quite sensible, **except** for the 5$ / month budget. Unlimited bandwidth for next to no money? No.

Comment: -1 I agree with Jesper

Comment: @Lo'oris: If the criteria can't be met, then the answer is simply "No", but that doesn't make it a bad question worthy of down voting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure it will check all your boxes, but I'm very impressed with [dropbox.com](http://www.dropbox.com)

Answer (score 1):

It does not meet all your criterias, but you could take a look at [drop.io](http://drop.io/), it is very usable.

That said, I don't know any service that offers real unlimited downloads/bandwidth.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.nearlyfreespeech.net/

It's *very* cheap, as in "pennies a month", but it might not be what you want.  Specifically, you pay for bandwidth, and if you use a good bit, it'll probably be pricier than one of the more traditional plans.